# Impurity concerns

Tags: muslim-practices

Salaam,
I wanted to ask a question. My husband has his phone in his trouser pocket when using the toilet. Does it make his phone dirty or impure?
I am suffering from major anxiety, i find everything dirty & keep washing my hands. After, using the toilet or having sex, i wash my hands & clean all the taps before using them. Plus, while washing my hands after using the toilet, what do i do if drops of water or handwash fall on my clothes. Does that make my clothes impure? Jazakallah khair.

Comment: Neither tahrah is a synonym of cleanness nor is najasah a synonym of dirth, both are rather terms for ritual purity/impurity. So how should a phone get impure while in a pocket while neither the pocket is impure nor the toilet itself is? You should learn the basics of Tahrah from scratch as knowledge is the best way to fight doubt and anxiety.

Answer (score -1):

Salaam,
No it doesn't. My brother suffers from the same problem, but I can assure you that it is just in your head. Shaitan sometimes distracts us with small things like this that can drive us crazy lol. One thing that is good is that you are conscious of when you are washing your hands. Now that you notice it, ask yourself: is this normal? Tell yourself that your hands are not dirty, and remind yourself daily. Hopefully, this will help you with the OCD issue. Also, make sure to make dua to Allah (swt) to make it easier for you. :)
Best,
Michelle

Comment: Please stop referring to your website in answers or we will regard them as [spam](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/spam-rude-and-abusive-flags)!